# How do I nicely cover this floor pipe in the basement?

Tags: basement, flooring, pipe

So I'm adding flooring to my basement and I've got this sewer access cap thing in the way. I know I need to wrap the flooring around it and then I assume I'll need to cover it with something.

What is this thing and what are my options to cover it to look like it kinda matches my flooring?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would create a fake duct vent. Cut floor the size of the vent, trim the vent base so it sits flush. If it looks like something you expect to see on the floor you will likely not notice it

Comment: It should be obvious that there is a cleanout here - it should not be "hidden" to the point that it's difficult to find when it needs to be found and used. So a cleanout cover plate (which any plumber would recognize instantly)  is highly preferable to a "fake vent" which conceals what it is.

Comment: Seriously - keep this accessible.  If your sewer line blocks up and you need to clean it out and you've buried the cleanout your plumbers will have to start ripping toilets out for a place to feed the snake - and believe me they will charge you for it.

Answer (score 17):

I would switch it out for a *flush cleanout plug* and paint it to match as close as possible. You should not cover or hide it because it is probably for sewer clean-out purposes.

[image]

Comment: They also make covers (slightly larger) that will dress up the finished look (there is a ring that goes around the pipe and fastens to the sub-floor, and a cover that goes in the ring which hides the actual plug under it and gives a tidy look at the finished floor level.)

Comment: Paint would be worn away in short order on a floor, leaving this looking pretty rough. How do you propose trimming out the cut in the flooring? I don't see how this is a solution.

Comment: The floor paint in my garage would challenge the assertion that it would be "worn away in short order". Two years ago I painted the ABS clean-out plugs in my driveway to match the pavers, they still look good. I guess it would depend on the paint type and amount of traffic. A decorative cover would probably be even nicer.

Comment: Your garage floor isn't plastic, and you haven't addressed the hole in the flooring. That's the primary issue.

Answer (score 4):

Replace your cleanout plug with the flush type that Jimmy Fix-it suggests. Use PTFE thread tape or thread compound for a good seal or just make sure it's tight.

Fit your flooring around it, then lay a stainless cover over the top. Drill through the cap to fit its mounting screw. You could support the center of the cover with a suitable stack of washers so it doesn't bounce if walked on.

[image]

Comment: FWIW you could make a cover like this out of a scrap of flooring material and hide it even better.

Comment: Greg, that seems like an answer or a comment on the question rather than a comment on this solution.

Comment: Your solution all the way, just a "tweak" to the concept.